# Scale Data per column pd

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that had values entered incorrectly such that the scale needed is 0-4 but it was entered as 0-5, what is the best way to scale down data such as the following table:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |

Comment: update with the result you expect, and any code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scale all values in your df, you can use

```
df = df*4/5

     a    b    c
0  0.0  1.6  4.0
1  4.0  3.2  2.4
2  0.8  3.2  1.6
3  2.4  3.2  0.0
```

recreating your input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 0, 1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 3}, 'b': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4}, 'c': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 0}})
```

Answer (score 0):

without assuming the the maximum value is 5, you can extract the maximum value and apply the scale down based on it:

```
df = df / df.max().max() * 4
print(df)
```

## input

```
 a  b   c
 2  5   5
 8  4   3
 1  4   2
 3  4   0
```

## output

```
   a    b    c
  1.0  2.5  2.5
  4.0  2.0  1.5
  0.5  2.0  1.0
  1.5  2.0  0.0
```